# array replaces instead of concatenating values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this array declared as

`rowData = []`

I want to update this array with a forloop but it keeps replacing the values instead of updating it. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

```
    rowDataDefs(){
        for (let to of this.detailedOrders){
            console.debug(to)
            this.rowData = [
                {table_no: to.table.tableNo, order_no: to.orderNo, date_time: to.table.createdDate }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well of course you are doing it wrong, you are _overwriting_ the variable in each loop iteration, instead of actually adding new items to it.

Comment: Consider pushing to the array? Or concatenating them?

Comment: Try using concat instead of replacing your array with the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

```
rowDataDefs(){
        for (let to of this.detailedOrders){
            console.debug(to)
            this.rowData.push(
                {table_no: to.table.tableNo, order_no: to.orderNo, date_time: to.table.createdDate });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier, unfortunately, it doesn't return any data for whatever reason.

Comment: It was from my JS after all. Thanks.

Comment: @MarvelousIkechi You need to return the new array. Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `array.push()` instead of replacing the same index(0th index) value every time.

```
 rowDataDefs(){
    for (let to of this.detailedOrders){
        console.debug(to)
        this.rowData.push(
            {
                table_no: to.table.tableNo, 
                order_no: to.orderNo, 
                date_time: to.table.createdDate 
            }
        )
    }
    return this.rowData;
 }
```